# Custom activity in WF 4.0: WorkflowItemsPresenter wont show converted array

Tags: c#, binding, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

we have an Array which is converted via a Binded Converter:

```
else if (TTools.IsOfBaseClass(value.GetType(), typeof(System.Activities.Presentation.Model.ModelItemCollection)))
        {

              OurBaseClass[] test = (value as ModelItemCollection).GetCurrentValue() as OurBaseClass[];
              List<OurBaseClass> listOfArray = new List<OurBaseClass>();
              foreach (OurBaseClass item in test)
                {
                     listOfArray.Add(item);
                }
                return listOfArray;

        }
```

the convertion works well but it is not shown in our dynamically gui

gui code with bindings:

```
<sap:WorkflowItemsPresenter xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:sap="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"  Grid.Column="0" Name="MyArray" Items="{Binding Path=ModelItem.MyArray}"  MinWidth="150" Margin="0">
                <sap:WorkflowItemsPresenter.SpacerTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock  Foreground="DarkGray" Margin="30">..</TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sap:WorkflowItemsPresenter.SpacerTemplate>
                <sap:WorkflowItemsPresenter.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </sap:WorkflowItemsPresenter.ItemsPanel>
            </sap:WorkflowItemsPresenter>
```

Why is the gui not shown as a List??? it works well without converter.
Thanks

Comment: want to tag this as workflow-foundation-4 but don't know how...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the converter?

I think the first problem may be that ModelItem.MyArray is type ModelProperty, rather than ModelItemCollection.